# iOS 8.3 modalPresentationStyle OverCurrentContext does not inherit status bar appearance and visibility

Tags: statusbar, uimodalpresentationstyle, ios8.3

Consider the following setup:

- You have a simple application with a single `UINavigationController` subclass and a single `UIViewController` subclass in it.
- The UINavigationController overrides `preferredStatusBarStyle()` method and returns `UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent`
- The UIViewController overrides `prefersStatusBarHidden()` method and returns `true`

In iOS 8.0 - 8.2 when another `UINavigationController` (with another UIViewController that does not override anything) is presented with the `modalPresentationStyle` set to `UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext`, the newly presented controller inherits the status bar appearance and visibility.

But in iOS 8.3 in the exact same situation - the newly presented controller does not inherits the status bar appearance and visibility

Another example would be to present an instance of `UIImagePickerController` - the exact same thing happens regarding the status bar appearance.

The questions are:

- Why in iOS 8.3 the newly presented controller does not inherit the status bar appearance?
- What has been changed (I was unable to find any meaningful reference in the iOS 8.2 to 8.3 API diff regarding this)?
- Is there any elegant solution to this, instead of overriding everywhere the appearance and visibility methods?

Answer (score 8):

Try that:

```
(viewControllerToBePresented).modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```

Comment: This has no effect on iOS 8.3+ but instead makes iOS 8.2- to behave in the problematic way like iOS 8.3+